# Boost Asio error code

Tags: c++, boost, asio

Есть два простеньких консольных приложения, которые выполняют роль сервера и тест клиента.

Код сервера:

```
#include <locale>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <array>


class Session
{
public:
    Session(boost::asio::io_service& io_service)
        : m_Socket(io_service)
    {
    }

    boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket& Socket()
    {
        return m_Socket;
    }

    void PostReceive()
    {
        memset(&m_ReceiveBuffer, '\0', sizeof(m_ReceiveBuffer));

        m_Socket.async_read_some(
            boost::asio::buffer(m_ReceiveBuffer),
            boost::bind(&Session::handle_receive, this,
            boost::asio::placeholders::error,
            boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));

    }


private:
    void handle_write(const boost::system::error_code& /*error*/, size_t /*bytes_transferred*/)
    {
    }

    void handle_receive(const boost::system::error_code& error, size_t bytes_transferred)
    {
        if (error)
        {
            if (error == boost::asio::error::eof)
            {
                std::cout << "diconnect..." << std::endl;
            }
            else
            {
                std::cout << "handle_receive error No: " << error.value() << " error Message: " << error.message() << std::endl;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            const std::string strRecvMessage = m_ReceiveBuffer.data();
            std::cout << "strRecvMessage: " << strRecvMessage << ", bytes: " << bytes_transferred << std::endl;

            char szMessage[128] = { 0, };
            sprintf_s(szMessage, 128 - 1, "Re:%s", strRecvMessage.c_str());
            m_WriteMessage = szMessage;

            boost::asio::async_write(m_Socket, boost::asio::buffer(m_WriteMessage),
                boost::bind(&Session::handle_write, this,
                boost::asio::placeholders::error,
                boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));

            PostReceive();
        }
    }

    boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket m_Socket;
    std::string m_WriteMessage;
    std::array<char, 128> m_ReceiveBuffer;
};

//todo: to args
const unsigned short PORT_NUMBER = 31400;

class Server
{
public:
    Server(boost::asio::io_service& io_service)
        : m_acceptor(io_service, boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint(boost::asio::ip::tcp::v4(), PORT_NUMBER))
    {
        m_pSession = nullptr;
        StartAccept();
    }

    ~Server()
    {
        if (m_pSession != nullptr)
        {
            delete m_pSession;
        }
    }

private:
    void StartAccept()
    {
        std::cout << "Starting accept..." << std::endl;

        m_pSession = new Session(m_acceptor.get_io_service());

        m_acceptor.async_accept(m_pSession->Socket(),
            boost::bind(&Server::handle_accept,
            this,
            m_pSession,
            boost::asio::placeholders::error)
            );
    }

    void handle_accept(Session* pSession, const boost::system::error_code& error)
    {
        if (!error)
        {
            std::cout << "handle accept" << std::endl;
            connectCount++;
            pSession->PostReceive();
        }
    }

    boost::asio::ip::tcp::acceptor m_acceptor;
    Session* m_pSession;
    int connectCount = 0;
};

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");

    boost::asio::io_service io_service;

    Server server(io_service);

    boost::system::error_code ec;

    io_service.run(ec);

    if (ec)
        std::cout << "io_service error No: " << ec.value() << " error Message: " << ec.message() << std::endl;

    getchar();

    return 0;
}
```

Код клиента:

```
#include <locale>
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/thread/thread.hpp> 


const char SERVER_IP[] = "192.168.56.1";
const unsigned short PORT_NUMBER = 31400;


class TestClient
{
public:
    TestClient(boost::asio::io_service& io_service)
        : m_io_service(io_service),
        m_Socket(io_service),
        m_nSeqNumber(0)
    {}

    void Connect(boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint& endpoint)
    {
        m_Socket.async_connect(endpoint,
            boost::bind(&TestClient::handle_connect,
            this,
            boost::asio::placeholders::error));
    }


private:
    void PostWrite()
    {
        if (m_Socket.is_open() == false)
        {
            return;
        }

        ++m_nSeqNumber;

        char szMessage[128] = { 0, };
        sprintf_s(szMessage, 128 - 1, "%d - Send Message", m_nSeqNumber);

        m_WriteMessage = szMessage;

        boost::asio::async_write(m_Socket, boost::asio::buffer(m_WriteMessage),
            boost::bind(&TestClient::handle_write, this,
            boost::asio::placeholders::error,
            boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));

        boost::this_thread::sleep(boost::posix_time::milliseconds(1000));

        PostReceive();
    }

    void PostReceive()
    {
        memset(&m_ReceiveBuffer, '\0', sizeof(m_ReceiveBuffer));

        m_Socket.async_read_some(boost::asio::buffer(m_ReceiveBuffer),
            boost::bind(&TestClient::handle_receive, this,
            boost::asio::placeholders::error,
            boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
    }


    void handle_connect(const boost::system::error_code& error)
    {
        if (error)
        {
            std::cout << "handle_connect connect failed error No: " << error.value() << " error Message: " << error.message() << std::endl;
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "connected" << std::endl;

            PostWrite();
        }
    }

    void handle_write(const boost::system::error_code& /*error*/, size_t /*bytes_transferred*/)
    {
    }

    void handle_receive(const boost::system::error_code& error, size_t bytes_transferred)
    {
        if (error)
        {
            if (error == boost::asio::error::eof)
            {
                std::cout << "Disconnect" << std::endl;
            }
            else
            {
                std::cout << "handle_receive error No: " << error.value() << " error Message: " << error.message() << std::endl;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            const std::string strRecvMessage = m_ReceiveBuffer.data();
            std::cout << "strRecvMessage: " << strRecvMessage << ", bytes: " << bytes_transferred << std::endl;

            PostWrite();
        }
    }



    boost::asio::io_service& m_io_service;
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket m_Socket;

    int m_nSeqNumber;
    std::array<char, 128> m_ReceiveBuffer;
    std::string m_WriteMessage;
};



int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");

    boost::asio::io_service io_service;

    boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint endpoint(boost::asio::ip::address::from_string(SERVER_IP), PORT_NUMBER);

    TestClient client(io_service);

    client.Connect(endpoint);

    boost::system::error_code ec;

    io_service.run(ec);

    if (ec)
        std::cout << "io_service error No: " << ec.value() << " error Message: " << ec.message() << std::endl;

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Вывод сервера:

```
Starting accept...
handle accept
strRecvMessage: 1 - Send Message, bytes: 16
strRecvMessage: 2 - Send Message, bytes: 16
strRecvMessage: 3 - Send Message, bytes: 16

handle_receive error No: 10054 error Message: Удаленный хост принудительно разор
вал существующее подключение
```

Вывод клиента:

```
connected
strRecvMessage: Re:1 - Send Message, bytes: 19
strRecvMessage: Re:2 - Send Message, bytes: 19
strRecvMessage: Re:3 - Send Message, bytes: 19
```

Ошибка 10054 возникает после остановки клиента путем закрытия консоли. После повторное подключение возможно, но сервер не отвечает.

Вопросы:
1)Как правильно обработать отключение так, что бы сервер не терял возможность отвечать на запросы?
2)Можно как то отправить "приветствие" при подключении, а потом просто оставить висеть подключение, как бы сигнализируя, что клиент в онлайне, или периодический пинг неизбежен?

Comment: @Abyx спасибо за наводку, разобрался :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Благодаря наводке Abyx, понял как решить проблему. Для этого достаточно добавить для сервера в метод handle_accept строчку `StartAccept()` для запуска принятия запросов:

```
void handle_accept(Session* pSession, const boost::system::error_code& error)
{
    if (!error)
    {
        std::cout << "handle accept" << std::endl;
        connectCount++;
        pSession->PostReceive();
    }

    StartAccept(); // <==
}
```